# Encrypted bucket notifications from S3 to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, amazon-kms

How can I set up S3 bucket notifications to a queue in SQS where KMS are used on both the bucket and the queue?

- I have a bucket in S3 where the contents are encrypted with an AWS Managed Key (the `aws/s3` default key).
- I have a queue in SQS where SSE (server-side encryption) is enabled, but using a CMK (Customer-Managed Key).

When I go into the S3 web console and try adding a notification event on my bucket that sends to my queue in SQS, I am presented with this error message:

> Unable to validate the following destination configurations. The message to the SSE queue could not be encrypted using KMS. (arn:aws:sqs:ca-central-1: ... : ...)

I've already tried configuring my KMS Key Policy to give the S3 service account the permissions it needs.

```
        {
            "Sid": "Let S3 encrypt messages so that bucket notifications can be encrypted",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:Encrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
```

What do I need to do in order to allow bucket notifications onto an encrypted queue?

Comment: Bucket and queue are in same region?

Answer (score 7):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/grant-destinations-permissions-to-s3.html#key-policy-sns-sqs), the second action should be `kms:Decrypt` instead of `kms:Encrypt`.

It's a bit counter-intuitive as to why `kms:Decrypt` is needed. You might be thinking that since the SQS queue is encrypted, so when the S3 service calls the [SendMessage API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html), it needs the `kms:Encrypt` permission to ensure that the message can be **encrypted** by the KMS service, right? Not quite, and here is why:

1. The message is **not** encrypted directly by the master key (CMK). Instead, it uses [envelope encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#enveloping), and the data is encrypted by the **data key**. Why? Because the maximum size of the data that a symmetric CMK can encrypt using the [Encrypt API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_Encrypt.html) is 4096 bytes, while the size of a message that the SQS service supports can be far greater than 4KB. Therefore, `kms:Encrypt` is **not** needed, and instead, `kms:GenerateDataKey` is required to generate the data key which is used to encrypt the SQS message.
2. In the section "Configure KMS permissions for producers" of [this AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-key-management.html), it explains why `kms:Decrypt` is needed.

> The call to `kms:Decrypt` is to verify the integrity of the new data key before using it.

To be abundantly clear, the [GenerateDataKey API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_GenerateDataKey.html) returns both the plaintext data key **and** the encrypted copy of the data key. The plaintext data key is used to encrypt the SQS message and the encrypted data key will be stored along with the message in the queue. The only way to verify that the encrypted data key is indeed the ciphertext of the plaintext data key is that the service needs to have the `kms:Decrypt` permission to decrypt the ciphertext and make sure the output is **exactly the same** as the plaintext data key returned in the GenerateDataKey API response.